# MySQL server is running but getting "Can't Connect"

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
(in /home/ahmet/x)

rake aborted!
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Is this a file permission error?

Comment: Is your socket `/tmp/mysql.sock`? Run the query like so: `bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace`

Comment: in /etc/my.cnf check the binding address.

Comment: in my.cnf socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is not currently a section called [client], try to add this lines at the end

```
[client]
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: I don't have permission on the file?

Comment: in your database.yml what is the ip you r using